# GCP Workload Identity Federation in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, workload-identity

We have a running spring boot aapplication in an on-prem server. our application uploading the files to GCS
I have been restricted to use Service account key and how to integerate the Workload Identity Federation in to onprem application

how to integerate the Workload Identity Federation in to onprem application

Comment: Google documentation: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation